# Microsoft account locks everytime PC goes to sleep, user cannot change password

Tags: entra-id, user-accounts

In this case I'm a frustrated user asking as my company (who shall remain nameless) IT department seems unable to diagnose the issue with this, and my own web searching can't find anything either.

My company runs servers hosted as VM's in Azure, part of the structure is our own domain controller which is kept in sync with Azure's user DC.

When ever my corporate domain linked laptop goes into sleep mode it locks my account, for access to the laptop and for accessing MS online web apps (outlook / office / etc).

I can self "fix" this by using the MS online password reset https://passwordreset.microsoftonline.com/passwordreset#!/ and selecting the "I know my password, but still can't login" option - and completing the 2FA test. Which gets me back into both the online web apps and corporate laptop.

I have to repeat this every time my laptop goes to sleep. And occasionally when the laptop tries to re-authenticate with the corporate VPN.

I have been through all of my devices phone, laptop, other PC's and cleared all cached credentials in case these were causing the account lockout.

In addition to this I am unable to change my password, either locally on the laptop or via the online password reset tool, with the error supplied stating that the new password doesn't meet the corporate requirements, I have tried passwords that do meet the requirements and ones that exceed them (including ones that meet any realistic options that might be set - 100+ chars UPPER, lower numbers, symbols) - which leads me to believe that the message displayed to me as the user isn't the real underlying cause.

My IT department have had to set my password for me, and ensure the "user must change password on next login" isn't toggled on for me to gain access to my account.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Can anyone suggest what *might* be causing the problem?

Many thanks.

PS: I know this is really a vague question, I have no access to logs or the user management side of the AzureAD. I'm hoping that some-one could provide some *possible* causes that I can suggest to the corporate IT department.